# Music Player Stuck partial wake locks (background)

Tags: android, wakelock, android-wake-lock, powermanager, android-powermanager

I have an android music player and I see a "Stuck partial wake locks (background)" in the Play Console. I'm not sure how to fix it. I search my code and the only code that I find is the following when I initialized the player.

```
    mPlayer.setWakeMode(getApplicationContext(), PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
    mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
```

Comment: Have you found a solution?  I have a similar query.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky Have you solved this problem? We've had it for a long time too.